# Can't fetch images of facebook app test user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, vue.js, facebook-apps

I have create an app on facebook and it allows users to login via facebook and fetch images of a user, which can be uploaded to different sections in my application.
When I use the same facebook account used to create the app, the seems to work fine, it fetches the images fine.
But when I login via the test user I have created on https://developers.facebook.com/apps/347947052791756/roles/test-users/?business_id=352816518942340 it allows me to login but does not allow me to fetch the images, it returns an empty response.

Can anyone guide me on why is this happening, and what I can do to prevent this?
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

User is logged in successfully but when I try to fetch the images it returns empty response.

```
facebook_token = "EAAE8dLx7d8wBAD8LsZABFDxS9CmV1UaiewOvA9s5m3xAsCngUJAEeZBLWU3SZC1Q6pnyjB83ASRdNZCER5uZAOxStVZCPXHALTSVTehBT1yS8Jri6O8JAsG9F9VTwQLh1q7DUmhMuoO5IA2mGcFqjmZBjx5igwHXF2ZBmD7FPE97aJRfl5iqCDR2ZCfPawmSen3fLLhPWfmHXwZDZD"
Facebook.get_object(
  facebook_token,
  'me/photos?fields=id,name,picture,images&limit=15'
)
```

But the above code returns empty response. It works fine when I try it on my local machine with my personal fb account. But on staging and with the facebook app test account it doesn't work.

Comment: does the test user even have pictures?

Comment: @luschn Yes the user do has pictures.